# Use specific method to socket server call

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I am using C# (Unity3D) and a TcpClient to connect to my socketserver. The URL I connect with is `ws://secure.mydomain.com`, but I need to specifically connect to the URL `ws://secure.mydomain.com/scoreTrack`.

This is how I initialise the connection:

```
string url = "secure.mydomain.com";
mySocket = new TcpClient();
mySocket.Client.Connect(url, port);

theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
```

If I set the url to `secure.mydomain.com/scoreTrack` I get a host not found error. However, I can't find a place to add a path to my URL so I write to that specific path.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What protocol is `ws://` the class `TcpClient` will not know how to interpret it.

Comment: The TCP client is for providing TCP communication, not WS communications.  The information you're trying to provide is a part of a higher level of abstraction.  You'll either need to manually figure out what TCP request to make for a given request in that protocol, or use a different client that works on a higher level of abstraction that can understand that protocol.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your comments! I am not very familiar with these protocols, but I have a working version now thanks to the free Unity plugin Socket.IO.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721

With this plugin I could easily set it up, using the full url "ws://secure.mydomain.com:80/scoreTrack".

Thanks again for your help.